# Is there a way to combine and sync two 2K cameras @ 90fps with ICs

Tags: computer-vision

I am searching for a way to minimize the size of a stereo vision module and cannot find any ICs that will combine and sync two MIPI CSI-2 (4 lane) data streams without an FPGA and too much code.  there was one online (MAX7366A 3D Video Combiner/Synchronizer with two MIPI CSI-2 Input and one MIPI CSI-2 output) but the product is not publicly available.   Does anyone have knowledge of an arrangement of ICs that I could try?.

Answer (score 1):

The OV580 from Omnivision will do what you are asking for, and provide you with a USB3 interface. There is a [product](https://www.leopardimaging.com/LI-OV580-STEREO.html) from leopard imaging with 2 MIPI CSI-2 interfaces. I think it will only work with certain Omnivision cameras though.

Answer (score 0):

Sony PS4 Camera is based on the same controller, for just $55. 
It USB3.0 cable but firmware connector. Price difference motivates [people](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heatsynclabs/SCJOrbMH1Y4) to hack but that is not easy walking.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @Eugene Bartosh. On Stack Exchange we are are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Your answer is a little terse.  Could you expand it?  What do you mean by "firmware connector"?

Comment: Sorry my answer may appear unclear... I mean that the device is based on USB3.0 controller, USB 3.0 cable (without USB 2.0 wires), and firmware connector is Sony's AUX, used for Sony PS4 Camera only (as soon as I know). More info is on [PS4 dev wiki](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/Aux )

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments or another answer. Please edit your original answer so this one can be deleted.